# How do I convert string array values to object in c#

Tags: c#

I have the following array:

```
"someData.childData.child1","someData.childData.child2", etc.
```

How do I convert this string array to objects. That is, someData.childData.child1, someData.childData.child2,... are all objects.

Comment: Have a look into .NET Reflection.

Comment: What do you mean by "converting to objects" ? do you want to evaluate the value of the specified object ("someData.childData.child1") ?

Comment: "someData.chidData.child1, someData.chidData.child2" are all objects or types? Using reflection you can work with types.

Comment: Yes, I want the evalute the value of the specified object.

Comment: This sort of seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)... what are you actually trying to do? reflection can give slower performance than potential alternatives

Comment: @SamarRizvi Once an object name is put into a string, its no more an object but just a string. If you want to maintain a list of objects to inspect, better you go with a Dictionary<key,value> or List<T> based on your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `Reflection` as follows

```
      string[] yourArray = new string[] { "someData.childData.child1", "someData.childData.child2" };
        System.Collections.Generic.List<dynamic> CreatedAll = new System.Collections.Generic.List<dynamic>();
        for (int i = 0; i < yourArray.Length; i++)
        {
            string objStr = yourArray[i];
            string[] objs = objStr.Split('.');
            System.Collections.Generic.List<dynamic> created = new System.Collections.Generic.List<dynamic>();
            for (int j = 0; j < objs.Length; i++)
            {
                var myObj = System.Activator.CreateInstance("namespaceName", objs[j]);
                created.Add(myObj);
            }

            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propertyInfo = created[1].GetType().GetProperty(objs[2]);
            propertyInfo.SetValue(created[1], created[2], null);


            System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propertyInfo1 = created[0].GetType().GetProperty(objs[1]);
            propertyInfo1.SetValue(created[0], created[1], null);
            CreatedAll.Add(created);
        }
```